# Syntax error displaying database fields in a gridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, relational-database, oledbconnection

I am doing a standard exercise where displaying fields of three tables in a gridview but however have a syntax error in my inner join statement.

Any advice perhaps on where the syntax error lies.

```
try
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;
                                Data Source =" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\Shopping List.mdb"));
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        OleDbDataAdapter dba = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT Ingredient.IngerdientId, Ingredient.IngredientName,  Area.AreaName, Recipe.RecipeName, Ingredient.Quantity 
                                                FROM Ingredient
                                                INNER JOIN Area ON Ingredient.AreaId = Area.AreaId
                                                INNER JOIN Recipe ON Ingredient.RecipeId = Recipe.RecipeId", conn);

        dba.Fill(ds);

        gridIngredients.DataSource = ds;
        gridIngredients.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        labMessage.Text = exe.Message; 

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you've misspelt `IngerdientId` in the SELECT part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Access db engine requires parentheses when your `FROM` clause includes more than one join.  I think this may do it, but you would be better off to build and test your `SELECT` statement within Access using its query designer if you can.

```
FROM (Ingredient
INNER JOIN Area ON Ingredient.AreaId = Area.AreaId)
INNER JOIN Recipe ON Ingredient.RecipeId = Recipe.RecipeId
```